# Saturation argument on countably infinite sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Let $A$ be a countably infinite set and $P(a)$ for $a \in A$ an arbitrary (logical) statement relative to the element $a$.

Given that for all $A' \subsetneq A$ with $\forall a' \in A': P(a')$ there is an $a \in A \setminus A'$, such that $P(a)$, can we conclude that $P(a)$ holds for arbitrary $a \in A$?

I'd appreciate the general idea for a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The OP uses "$\subsetneq$" for exactly that reason.

Comment: Sorry. I missed the not equal mark on the sign. It's rather small and my eyes are tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a well-ordering at all. Define $A' = \{a \in A : P(a)\}$, if $A' \ne A$, then there must be an $a \in A \setminus A'$ such that $P(a)$ holds, in contradiction to the definition of $A'$.