# Clarification on type of proof argument

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, nonstandard-analysis

I am wondering what it means to prove something via the *saturation argument*. I have seen this appear in a number of questions, but I am not sure as to what a *saturation argument* is. Any help would be appreciated.

---

Original Post: Saturation Argument in Analysis: Everything is in the title. I'm French and I don't understand the meaning.

Examples of where this has appeared:

**Example 1**: By a *saturation argument*, show that $F$ is continuous on $(-1,1)$ where $F$ is defined as $$F(x) := \int_{-\pi }^{\pi }\ln (1 + x^2 - 2x\cos \theta) d\theta, \quad x \in (-1,1).$$

**Example 2**: By a *saturation argument*, show that the series $S$, defined as  $$S(x)=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^x}$$ is continuous on $(1,+\infty)$.

---

Places where this phrasing appears includes: [http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/Math699/lecnotes.pdf](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Eross/Math699/lecnotes.pdf)

Comment: Could you give an example of when this phrase is used?

Comment: example of this concept https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1453029/saturation-argument-on-countably-infinite-sets

Comment: From looking at your reference, in generality, I think it just means that you *consider all the possible cases* within a certain argument. I don't believe this is a phrase that often appears in analysis.

You tagged your question with [sequences-and-series]. Is there a particular question that this phrase appears in?

Comment: @ ValidNinja I edited my question and gave examples

Comment: This type of phrasing appears in http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ross/Math699/lecnotes.pdf
quite frequently, and may be of use. I'm not familiar with this phrase but this is best I could find. It seems to appear quite frequently in non-standard analysis.